# jQuery Toggle [hidden] Attribute Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, hidden, attr

Whats the best way to toggle the new "Bootstrap 4" [hidden]-Attribute.
 Not just hiding and showing the element with "display: block" but rather removing and adding the **Attribute**.

```
<button type="button" hidden class="hideMe btn  btn-sm">Get Video</button> 
<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```

is there a better Way like this: http://jsfiddle.net/49u2q/123/

```
$('button.toggle').on('click',function() {
    if ($('button.hideMe ').is('[hidden]')) {
        $('button.hideMe ').removeAttr('hidden');
    } else {
        $('button.hideMe ').attr('hidden','');
    }
});
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/49u2q/124/   $(this).prev(".hidden").toggle();

Comment: need a dynamic solution

Comment: How is it not dynamic?

Comment: @dazzafact Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using **`toggle()`**

```js
$('button.toggle').on('click',function() {
  var bool=$(".video_btn").is(":hidden")
  $(".video_btn").toggleClass('hidden')
  $(".video_btn").attr('hidden',!bool)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" hidden class="hidden video_btn btn  btn-sm">Get Video</button>

<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: "hidden" will not toggle. try other attribute like "MySpecialattribut"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.toggle', function() {
  if ($(this).siblings('button.hidden').is('[hidden]')) {
    $(this).siblings('button.hidden').removeAttr('hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('button.hidden').attr('hidden','');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" hidden class="hidden btn  btn-sm">Get Video</button>
<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: no that will not toggle the attribut, just hide/shown it

Answer (score -1):

I see you are looking to play with hidden attribute so try this:

```js
$('button.toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($("button.hideMe").attr("hidden")) {
        $("button.hideMe").attr("hidden", false)
    } else $("button.hideMe").attr("hidden", true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" hidden class="hideMe btn  btn-sm">Get Video</button> 
<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Your `else` statement should be surrounded by curly braces `{ }`

Answer (score -1):

OK, heres a writte plugin solution:
I tought it works without any plugin and an existing jquery function :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/49u2q/127/

```
$.fn.toggleAttr = function(attr) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
        if (self.is('['+attr+']')) {
        self.removeAttr(attr)
    }else{
      self.attr(attr,1)
    }
  });
};


$('button.toggle').on('click',function() {
$('.hiddens').toggleAttr('hidden');

});
```